# Advice on how I can go about writting this program?

Tags: autohotkey

For a long time, I have been going through [THESE](https://i.imgur.com/9s7YfGg.png) types of devices in hopes of getting a hardware interface that is pressure sensitive and also provides tactile feedback. The closest I have gotten was the space mouse by 3DConnextion. It was perfect, The input rate was proportional to how much pressure I was applying to the knob but its plagued with proprietary  implementation, thus only a handful of software's support it.

But mostly importantly with all these devices, if I wanted the device to be driven by AHK code, I had to essentially turn them into dummy mouse/keyboard devices. Which would nullify their selling point (pressure sensitive/tactile feedback)

While using Autodesk Maya, I came across a solution. I realised the solution was all along right under my nose, my trusty mouse:

- First class citizen in AHK
- First class citizen in any software
- Already very good at operating it

##### But how does a mouse act as an interface that is pressure sensitive and also provides tactile feedback?

By dragging the mouse either along `X` or `Y` axis:

- Mouse drag speed = Pressure sensitivity, how fast to increment
- Mouse direction = knob direction, dragging left will decrement values and dragging right will increment values

[HERE](https://i.imgur.com/HoUw9Rw.gif) is a little demonstration of what I am talking about. Moving mouse left the animation goes back by 1 frame, moving mouse right the animation goes forward by 1 frame, as you can see, I can go very slow (frame by frame) to scrubbing extremely fast. I have a pretty good gaming mouse. The whole operation provides perfect tactile feedback, down to the pixel level.

So to implement the same feature found in Maya, in a 2D animation software:

- Moving mouse left the animation goes back by 1 frame by sending `Left` arrow key , the software's keyboard shortcut **Step 1 frame back**
- Moving mouse right the animation goes forward by 1 frame by sending `Right` arrow key , the software's keyboard shortcut  **Step 1 frame forward**

The thing is am stuck on how I can actually go about implementing this in AutoHotkey as a general operation that can be bound to any key, It gets even more complicated because I want to also take advantage of both the `X` and `Y` axis.

Lets say for example, while the `Space` key is down held down, for every **10 pixels** the mouse moves:

- **Up**, trigger `SendInput, {up}`
- **Down**, trigger `SendInput, {Down}`
- **Left**, trigger `SendInput, {Left}`
- **Right**, trigger `SendInput, {Right}

After an hour of mucking about, the following is what I have:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#Warn, All, OutputDebug
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 500
SetBatchLines, -1

Return
~space::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, StartX, StartY
ToolTip, % "StartX: " StartX "`nStartY1: " Starty          ;Temporary, for Debugging
KeyWait, Space
Sleep, 500                                                 ;Temporary sleep command for diffrentiating "Start" and "current" Tooltip
MouseGetPos, CurrentX, CurrentY
ToolTip, % "CurrentX: " CurrentX "`nCurrentY: " CurrentY   ;Temporary, for Debugging

If(CurrentX > StartX)
    SendInput, {Right}

If(CurrentX < StartX)
    SendInput, {Left}

If(CurrentY > StartY)
    SendInput, {Up}

If(CurrentY < StartY)
    SendInput, {Down}

Return
Esc::ExitApp
```

Its not working code, I feel my AHK knowledge is being tested to its limit. I think I am stuck on establishing the core underlying mechanism, which seem to be at `If(CurrentX < StartX)` but I cant quite figure it out.

How do I for example routinely check if there is a difference of 10 pixels between `StartX` and `CurrentX`

Is it even necessary to check for such a difference? I would appreciate any input and examples of how I can go about this. Thank you.

---

EDIT 1:
So after some more experimenting I came up with this, which sort of works:

```
#singleinstance, force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#Warn, All, OutputDebug
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 500
SetBatchLines, -1

Return
space::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
while GetKeyState("space", "p")
    {
    StartX := CurrentX
    StartY := CurrentY
    MouseGetPos, CurrentX, CurrentY
    
    Sleep, 555
    ToolTip, % "StartX: " StartX "`nStartY1: " StartY
    Sleep, 555
    If(CurrentX > StartX)
        ToolTip, CurrentX > StartX

    If(CurrentX < StartX)
        ToolTip, CurrentX < StartX

    If(CurrentY > StartY)
        ToolTip, CurrentY > StartY

    If(CurrentY < StartY)
    Tooltip, CurrentY < StartY
    }

Return
Esc::ExitApp
```

When I move 1 pixel to the **Left**, the message `CurrentX < StartX` is printed
When I move 1 pixel to the **Right**, the message `CurrentX > StartX` is printed

When I move 1 pixel to the **Up**, the message `CurrentY < StartY` is printed
When I move 1 pixel to the **Down** , the message `CurrentY > StartY` is printed

But its extremely error prone, as the threshold is only 1 pixel, attempting to move 1 pixel up can sometimes be taken as 1 pixel left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom threshold (e.g 10 pixels) in the auto-execute section:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

threshold=10

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

space::
    while GetKeyState("space", "p")
    {
        MouseGetPos, X1, Y1
        Sleep, 500
        MouseGetPos, X2, Y2
        
        If (X2 > X1+threshold)
            SendInput, {Right}
            
        If(X2 < X1-threshold)
            SendInput, {Left}

        If(Y2 > Y1+threshold)
            SendInput, {Down}

        If(Y2 < Y1-threshold)
            SendInput, {Up}             
    }
return
```

**EDIT:**

Try also this:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

threshold = 10

space::
    X1 := ""
    Y1 := ""
    while GetKeyState("space", "p")
    {
        X2 := X1
        Y2 := Y1
        MouseGetPos, X1, Y1
        dX := dX = "" ? X1 - X2 : dX + X1 - X2      
        dY := dY = "" ? Y1 - Y2 : dY + Y1 - Y2

        if (dX**2 >= threshold**2)
        {
            SendInput % (dX > 0 ? "{Right}" : "{Left}")
            dX -= threshold * ((dX > 0) * 2-1)
        }
        
        if  (dY**2 >= threshold**2)
        {
            SendInput % (dY > 0 ? "{Down}" : "{up}")
            dY -= threshold * ((dY > 0) * 2-1)
        }
    }
return
```

Comment: Hey I tried your code, I cant really tell if the threshold is doing what its supposed to be doing, but that aside your solution does not seem to correlate mouse movement with the arrow keys. For example with a 500 milli second delay, I can move the mouse 100 pixels right but `Right` is only sent  sent once or twice. I am looking for Nth mouse movement=1 Arrow key being sent. The culprit seems to be the `Sleep, 500`  yet adjusting it does not seem to help.